# Plain Javascript XLSX Style

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I have client-side plain JavaScript code that I'm trying to run in a web browser to create a stylized XLSX file. I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style).

The examples seem to use the following libraries:

- cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/shim.min.js
- cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js

But it doesn't seem to work with styling the cells. Here is some code I have:

```
var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
var worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([data],{origin:"B2"});

worksheet["B2"].s = { fill: { bgColor: { rgb: "88997788" } } };

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook,worksheet,'Grades');
XLSX.writeFile(workbook,'Grades.xlsx');
```

All the data is in the right place within the XLSX file and it downloads fine, but cell B2 remains plain - no styling.